# Django queryset 'in' operator fails on first call

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

When using the 'in' operator on a queryset, the first time the call is made it fails.

**Edit 4:**

I have simplified my problem down to the following piece of code which should be easy for anybody to test.

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Project(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='projects')    


category_list = Category.objects.prefetch_related('projects')


print category_list # [<Category: Category object>, <Category: Category object>]
print category_list[0] in category_list # False
print category_list[0] in category_list # True
```

If I remove 'prefetch_related' and use 'all' instead then the problem is gone, however this uses many more DB calls.

How can I get the correct result first time using prefetch_related?

Comment: This sounds like a bug in your application logic, do more testing or add the view code.

Comment: Please add the view source code.

Comment: Just what thnee and adrianp said - the bug is more than probably elsewhere. Also it's a very inefficient way to filter out "inactive" categories or treat them differently...

Comment: This looks like a valid question to me. Whats wrong with it?

Comment: That one who down voted this question, don't like this.

Answer (score 0):

In the Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) it shows the same code as you have but with an `.all()` in front of the prefetch_related.

Perhaps in the absence of that Django may be being too lazy with the query? I thought it might be waiting til the first slice [0] and interpreting that as a query (LIMIT 0) but that doesn't explain the print statement showing everything there. Either way, it looks like a bug - can't imagine this is the 'expected behaviour'.

Can you try it with the `.all()` in and report the output?

Comment: Yep. I tried with .all() and it didn't fix the problem. I opened a bug ticket which has been accepted. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20242